# Error building openVPN Key

Tags: openvpn

I am having issues building keys for my openVPN. I Just finished making the ca-key with openVPN in Ubuntu Server 16.04. After is use ./build-key and i receive error "/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pkitool: 293: shift: can't shift that many" I have recently purged openVPN and tried to start again and i wasn't receiving this error before so i am confused.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. I wasn't putting my server's name in when i was build the server key.

Comment: More specifically, it's necessary to call the command with the Common Name as an argument like so:

`./build-key-server "Example CA"`

Answer (score 0):

"etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pkitool: 293: shift: can't shift that many" error can also happen if you lack permissions to the folder and requisite ssl folders (/etc/ssl).

Quick solution is just to do "sudo su" as root and complete your task, then "exit" when done.

I know this is old, but this was a top search result for the error message and the solution was non-obvious from the error message.